# Delegating change event on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fire a function whenever the value of an input field changes. The input field is in a lightbox so I have to delegate the event:

```
var validateDonation = function(elem) {
  var msg,
      value = elem.value;

  if (value == '') { msg = 'Please enter an amount'; }
  else if(parseInt(value, 10) < 1) { msg = 'Please enter an amount greater than 1'; }
  else if(parseInt(value, 10) > 100) { msg = 'Please enter an amount less than 100'; }
  else { msg = ''; }


  if(msg != '') {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

and

```
$('body').delegate('#donation_amount', 'change', function(event) {
  validateDonation(this);
});
```

If I use `keyup` instead of `change` the console log works just fine. But not on change. Why?

Comment: can you try $('body').on('change' , '#donation_amount', function(event) {
  validateDonation(this);
});

Comment: The change event doesn't even fire when the input is blurred and should fire the change event? or the event is firing upon change (blur of input) however you want the event to fire anytime the value of the input box changes instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(v=vs.85).aspx

*onchange: This event is fired when the contents are committed and not while the value is changing. For example, on a text box, this event is not fired while the user is typing, but rather when the user commits the change by leaving the text box that has focus. In addition, this event is executed before the code specified by onblur when the control is also losing the focus.*

If you want the change to be instantly updated then you would want to use the **oninput** event

*oninput: The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed. Additionally, it fires on contenteditable editors when its contents are changed.*

For IE less than IE9 i believe you need to use the onpropertychange event as well as oninput to accommodate modern browsers.

Here is a fiddle to show you the event fires immediately

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/9jfkcapp/

**Try this...**

```
$('body').delegate('#donation_amount', 'input propertychange', function (event) {
    validateDonation(this);
});
```